# Replacing the first 2 strings of similar characters in the column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I want to replace the first 2 characters of all entries that starts with "01" with "A0".

table = Seq

```
Column1
01010101
01010102
01010103
```

result should be:

```
Column1
A0010101
A0010102
A0010103
```

I can't use the replace because I don't want to change the succeeding "01".

```
Update [Seq]
Set Column1 = Replace(Column1, '01', 'A0')
Where Column1 like '01%'
```

I'm hoping to use `Stuff` instead, but I can't seem to make it work.

```
Update [Seq]
Set Column1 = 'A0' + substring(Column1, 2, len(Column1)-6)
where Column1 like '01%'
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Update [Seq]
Set Column1 = 'A0' + RIGHT(Column1, LEN(Column1) - 2)
where Column1 like '01%'
```

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/MFI19774)

Using [**`STUFF`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx):

```
Update [Seq]
Set Column1 = STUFF(Column1, 1, 2, 'A0') 
where Column1 like '01%'
```

Comment: @Gordon I fail to see the point in checking  `Column1 like 'A0%'`

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos . . . I was thinking more generally, probably by focusing on the first sentence.